# Java parallelStream() with reduce() not improving performance

Tags: java, optimization, concurrency, java-8

As a test of Java 8's new implementation of streams and automatic parallelization, I ran the following simple test:

```
ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=1; i<49999999; i++) nums.add(i);

int sum=0;
double begin, end;

begin = System.nanoTime();
for (Integer i : nums) sum += i;
end = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println( "1 core: " + (end-begin) );

begin = System.nanoTime();
sum = nums.parallelStream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
end = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println( "8 cores: " + (end-begin) );
```

I thought summing up a series of integers would be able to take great advantage of all 8 cores, but the output looks like this:

```
1 core: 1.70552398E8
8 cores: 9.938507635E9
```

I am aware that nanoTime() has issues in multicore systems, but I doubt that's the problem here since I'm off by an order of magnitude.

Is the operation I'm performing so simple that the overhead required for reduce() is overcoming the advantage of multiple cores?

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with autoboxing... Test it with an int array and a counter?

Comment: Note that `parallelSteam()` doesn't always use all of your cores.

Comment: What autoboxing? Everything is an Integer. Changing `sum` to an Integer also does not affect the performance in any way.

Comment: Also note that this is *not* a  proper benchmark. Use a microbenchmarking tool (like jmh) in order to *really* check performance differences.

Comment: Setting aside benchmarking flaws, it is quite possible for the overhead of parallel streams to swamp the speedup from multiple cores. See [When to use Parallel Streams](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/StreamParallelGuidance.html) for a discussion of these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stream example has 2 unboxings (`Integer.sum(int,int)`) and one boxing (the resulting `int` has to be converted back to an `Integer`) for every number whereas the for loop has only one unboxing. So the two are not comparable.

When you plan to do calculations with Integers it's best to use an `IntStream`:

```
nums.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
```

That would give you a performance similar to that of the for loop. A parallel stream is still slower on my machine.

The fastest alternative would be this btw:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 49999999).sum();
```

An order of a magnitude faster and without the overhead of building a list first. It's only an alternative for this special use case, of course. But it demonstrates that it pays off to rethink an existing approach instead of merely "add a stream".

Comment: `return nums.parallelStream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();` runs faster than the for loop but only by a factor of 2 on my 12 core machine. Nothing to write home about :-(

Comment: @assylias: your method works the fastest on my machine

Answer (score 1):

To properly compare this *at all*, you need to use similar overheads for both operations.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 49999999; i++)
        nums.add(i);

    int sum = 0;
    long begin, end;

    begin = System.nanoTime();
    sum = nums.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
    end = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("1 core: " + (end - begin));

    begin = System.nanoTime();
    sum = nums.parallelStream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
    end = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("8 cores: " + (end - begin));
```

This lands me

```
1 core:  769026020
8 cores: 538805164
```

which is in fact quicker for `parallelStream()`. (Note: I only have 4 cores, but `parallelSteam()` does not always use all of your cores anyways)

Another thing is boxing and unboxing. There is boxing for `nums.add(i)`, and unboxing for everything going into `Integer::sum` which takes two `int`s. I converted this test to an array to remove that:

```
    int[] nums = new int[49999999];
    System.err.println("adding numbers");
    for (int i = 1; i < 49999999; i++)
        nums[i - 1] = i;

    int sum = 0;
    System.err.println("begin");
    long begin, end;

    begin = System.nanoTime();
    sum = Arrays.stream(nums).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
    end = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("1 core: " + (end - begin));

    begin = System.nanoTime();
    sum = Arrays.stream(nums).parallel().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
    end = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("8 cores: " + (end - begin));
```

And that gives an unexpected timing:

```
1 core:   68050642
8 cores: 154591290
```

It is much faster (1-2 orders of magnitude) for the linear reduce with regular ints, but only about 1/4 of the time for the parallel reduce and ends up being slower. <strike>I'm not sure why that is, but it is certainly interesting!</strike>

Did some profiling, turns out that the `fork()` method for doing parallel streams is very expensive because of the use of `ThreadLocalRandom`, which calls upon network interfaces for it's seed! This is very slow and is the only reason why `parallelStream()` is slower than `stream()`!

Some of my VisualVM data: (ignore the `await()` time, that's the method I used so I could track the program)
For first example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z7qf2es0lxs6fvu/streams1.nps?dl=0
For second example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f3ydl4basv7mln5/streams2.nps?dl=0

TL;DR: In your `Integer` case it looks like parallel wins, but there is some overhead for the `int` case that makes parallel slower.

Comment: Updated with data on `parallelStream()` being slow.

Comment: You benchmark is flawed (does not wait for JIT compilation, does not use the result of the operation under test which could be completely skipped by the JIT, ...). I suggest using a proper benchmarking environment such as jmh.

Comment: I understand that the benchmark is flawed, however any benchmarking tools I try to use end up breaking on me. If you have got better data, put it up somewhere and I can add it.

Comment: *Please*, don’t use `double` variables to store `long` values. That really hurts…

Comment: @Holger I tried to keep my code modifications down, I can fix that.

Comment: Ok, I swapped out anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think boxing of add(i) is irrelevant as it is not measured (it's pre-computed), which is why I didn't include it. I also mentioned the boxing of sum in my first comment to the first responder, which is also trivial and has little effect. Removing the boxing of Integer::sum also had little to no effect on my machine. Your observation of the networking call may be the correct reason.

Comment: @ıɯɐƃoʇǝızuǝʞ Your methodology is totally busted, so the results are pretty meaningless.  It is badly biased by all manner of startup anomalies, and worse, differentially so.  If you have known-bogus data, probably best to avoid using it as the basis for performance advice ...

Comment: @BrianGoetz, okay, what do you want me to do? I can't test this any better.

Comment: @ıɯɐƃoʇǝızuǝʞ While I understand what you're saying about benchmarking (and it is true in general), many repetitions of this simple test by multiple users can confirm the behavior I was investigating. Many years of experience have also taught me that very simple benchmarking experiments like this rarely fail by a substantive margin. Thanks again for all your input.